# C++ Template specialisation issue

Tags: c++

I have code that boils down to this:

```
//Just a templated array class .. implementation doesn't matter
template<int N>
struct Array {};

//A simple Traits like class
template<typename T>
struct MyTraits {}

//Specialization of the traits class
template<int N>
struct Foo< Array<N> >
{
  static void monkey() {};
}

int main()
{
  Foo< Array<3> >::monkey();
}
```

Unfortunately the compiler doesn't like it...

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp|17| error: ‘monkey’ is not a member of ‘Foo<Array<3> >’
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Am I missing something, or do you not use your traits class? Is `Foo` suppose to be `MyTraits`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
//Just a templated array class .. implementation doesn't matter
template<int N>
struct Array {};

//A simple Traits like class
template<typename T>
struct MyTraits {};

//Specialization of the traits class
template<int N>
struct MyTraits< Array<N> >
{
    static void monkey() {};
};

int main()
{
    MyTraits< Array<3> >::monkey();
}
```

The way you have `Foo` is incorrect, as you can see I changed it to match the comment. Additionally, you had a missing semicolon after the declaration of `Foo`/`MyTraits`. Lastly, for an array class I would recommend you use `size_t` as the type of `N`.

Comment: You're spot on on those issues. Mostly they were caused by copy, paste and fix issues. Looks like my problem lies somewhere else :(

Comment: Feel free to post more code, preferably real code. :) We'd like to get your problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested the problem was this:

```
template<unsigned int N>
class V {};

template<typename T>
struct MyTraits
{
};

template< int N>
struct MyTraits< V<N> >
{
  static void monkey();
};

int main()
{
  MyTraits< V<4> >::monkey( );
}
```

Generates this error

```
error: ‘monkey’ is not a member of ‘MyTraits<V<4u> >’
```

This caused by a mismatch between the template type being an unsigned int in one spot and an int in another. (Kind of ugly)

Changing the traits specialization to be

```
template< unsigned int N>
struct MyTraits< V<N> >
{
  static void monkey();
};
```

makes everything work. (This issue was obscured as the definition of V is in 3rd party code).